# Como imprimir um valor hexadecimal em caixa alta?

Tags: c++, string, stream

Fiz um programa em C++ que lê um número e imprime ele em hexadecimal, segue o código abaixo.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    int n;  
    cin>>n; 
    cout<<hex<<n<<endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Só que ele imprime tudo em minusculo e eu gostaria que imprimisse em maísculo, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É só user o `uppercase`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int n;  
    cin >> n; 
    cout << uppercase << hex << n << endl; 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fXQAZD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/eapklzwo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/Uppercase.cpp).

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase).